# Roku Advertising Framework Clickthrough Link

Tags: roku, vast

I am using the Roku Advertising Framework at the moment to request video ads from an ad server using VAST tags. I am wondering, if it is possible to use the `<ClickThrough>` tag of the VAST 2.0 format to link to another Roku channel - so if the user clicks on the ad, the Roku channel is opened in the Roku channel store.

I already tried it with the web link, so for example a link like "https://channelstore.roku.com/details/8378/hbo-go", which didn’t work. And I also tried it using a deep link with a "/install/channelId" parameter, which also didn’t work (probably because this must be done using a POST request, but in VAST tags we can of course only integrate pure URLs (=GET request)). In both cases, when tapping on any button on the remote during the video playback, nothing is happening. Also no call to action is shown (even though this is not too important in my case).

Is there a way to link to another Roku channel just by using the VAST format in combination with the RAF? In the RAF Documentation, it is said the `<ClickThrough>` tag is supported, but there is no explanation how to create links to other channels or how to use it in general: https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Roku+Advertising+Framework#RokuAdvertisingFramework-CurrentFeatures

Answer (score 0):

My initial thoughts were to have a look at the [External Control Guide](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/External+Control+Guide), but it looks like you already thought of that and I think you need to aim those requests at the IP address of the individual box, which might be tricky to do with a `<ClickThrough>` tag. I don't know if there are any other solutions.